# Date time format in excel 08/23/2016 6:45:10 AM, I want to get this data into ORACLE database in timestamp format

Tags: sql, oracle

Date time format in excel 08/23/2016 6:45:10 AM, I want to get this data into ORACLE database in timestamp data type but able to do so. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

TO_DATE allows you to specify the input format and then converts to the Oracle DATE format.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

TO_DATE allows you to specify the input format and then converts to the Oracle DATE format.

or https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Comment: I think you got it wrongly.  When I am trying to import from excel to Oracle, it is stored as date but not the timestamp data type.

Comment: Then use TO_TIMESTAMP to get the time part of it, look at the date functions and pick the one that is what you're trying to achieve.